# webpy: how to override content of basic template?

Tags: python, templates, overriding, web.py

I'm using webpy with a basic template

```
render = web.template.render(basedir + 'templates/', base='layout', globals=globals_vars_custom)
```

in `layout.html` I have something like:

```
$def with (content)
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PAGE TITLE</title>
        <!-- Some CSS and some javascript -->
    </head>
    <body>
        $:content
    </body>
</html>
```

This basic template works fine for the 90% of my site, but I have a page in which I need to insert some other data inside the `<head>` (some meta tags).

How can I do this? How can I put the `<head>` inside a structure that I can easily override inside a template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was easier than I tought:

You can create a variable in a template:

in page.html you can define a variable

```
$var title = 'specific title'
```

in the base template layout.html you can call the varable:

```
$def with (content)
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>$content.get("title","DEFAULT TITLE")</title>
        <!-- Some CSS and some javascript -->
    </head>
    <body>
        $:content
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this answer can be useful also for other people.